# Relationship between asymptotic distribution and logarithmic sums of elements of subset of the natural numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

Consider a subset $A$ of the natural numbers analogous to the primes (but rarer). Let $a_n$ denote the $n$th element of $A$, and $a(n)$ denote the number of elements of $A$ less than or equal to $n$ (analogous to $p_n$ and $\pi(n)$ respectively).

Define $$b(n)=\sum_{a \le n}\log a$$ where the sum is taken over those elements of $A$ less than or equal to $n$ and $\log$ denotes the natural logarithm, analogous to Chebyshev's theta function $\vartheta(x)$. What in general is the relationship between $b(n)$ and $a(n)$? Specifically, if we know that $$b(n)\gg \log n \tag{$*$}$$ what bounds can we place on $a(n)$?

I have been unable to come up with a method for this other than plugging in various approximations to $a(n)$ and testing which are compatible with $(*)$. Guessing from the case $A=\mathbf P$ of the primes, I hazard that when given $(*)$ $a(n) \gg {\sqrt n\over \log n}$, which seems to work reasonably well, but I am not confident in my calculations and even if they are correct this may not be the most accurate answer.

Comment: You can find a link using partial summation. In fact $$\underset{a\leq n}{\sum}\log\left(a\right)=a\left(n\right)\log\left(n\right)-\int_{1}^{n}\frac{a\left(t\right)}{t}dt.$$

Comment: @MarcoCantarini Thanks. How can I evaluate (or approximate) the integral without a direct approximation of $a(n)$ from $b(n)$? In $(*)$, the integral term becomes the main term and I can't figure out how to attack it.

Comment: I think you need some more information about $a(n)$. I don't see in this moment non-trivial manipulations.

Comment: Assuming that $1 \notin A$ (add one otherwise), we can also write $$a(x) = \frac{b(x)}{\log x} + \int_2^x \frac{b(t)}{t(\log t)^2}\,dt\,.$$ Knowing either of $a$ and $b$ sufficiently well gives you information about the other, but if you know not much, you don't get much out of it. From $b(x) \gg \log x$ we obtain $a(x) \gg \log \log x$ from the summation by parts, but that's it. If $a_k = 2^{2^k}$ we have $a(x) \sim \frac{\log \log x}{\log 2}$ and $b(x) \in \Theta(\log x)$.